# How to reopen all files under default change to another specific change?

Tags: perforce

I have lots of files opened in perforce. 
Some of them are under a specific change.
All other files are under default change.
How do I reopen all files under default change to that specific change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want all the files to be open under specific change 1234:

```
p4 reopen -c 1234 //...
```

In the situation you describe, this will work fine since all of your files that aren't open in the default change are already open under 1234.

If you have multiple numbered changelists and you want only the files in the default change to be reopened under change 1234:

```
p4 -F %depotFile% opened -c default | p4 -x - reopen -c 1234
```